# Div's "display:none" causes the elements not accessible from code behind

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src="Images/a1.png"/>
</div>
```

`display:none;` attribute makes `Image1` not accessible from the CodeBehind. If I remove `display:none;` works fine. How can hide the div and access to elements within it from server side?

Comment: No, it should be accessible even if another html element has some style.Is it on top of the page? If so, try to rename it to `Image2`, save and rename it to `Image1` again. Otherwise it's not accessible and you need to use `FindControl` or other ways to get the reference.

Comment: Tried to rename it, didn't make any difference. `FindControl` got the job done. Thanks. I am still surprising with not being able to access it straight through.

Comment: it depends on if the `Page` itself is the `NamingContainer` of the `Image` or another container control which implements `INamingContainer`(like `ContentPlaceHolder` of a master-page or `GridViewRow` of a `GridView`). Then you have to use `FindControl` on the namingcontainer or expose it it another way (f.e. by providing a property in the masterpage which returns the image, in case it's in  a `ContentPlaceHolder`).